# how find file in project

Tags: ios, swift

I am desperate with looking for a file in my project..

I have a file: Database.sqlite3 in Supporting files with Interface.plist etc.

This code found plist but no database:

```
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let envsPListPath = bundle.pathForResource("Interface", ofType:"plist")
    let environments = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: envsPListPath!)
```

How can i get path to the database file, please? I did try a lot of solution, but for Documents in mobile not in project directory.

Comment: Did you try the obvious of: `bundle.pathForResource("Database", ofType:"sqlite3")`?

Comment: post the code you used to try find the `database.sqlite3` file

Comment: yes i did and always "nil"

Comment: If it's `nil` then you don't actually have a file named `Database.sqlite3` in your app bundle. Make sure the case of the filename matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   let strDbPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Database", ofType:"sqlite")
```

by this you can the path full path of your sqlite in the bundle after you get that path you can access according to your requirement
generally copied in to document directory for further operations

It can be access by this way also

```
class func copyFile(fileName: NSString) {
        let dbPath: String = getPath(fileName as String)
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath) {

            let documentsURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL
            let fromPath = documentsURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName as String)

            var error : NSError?
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(fromPath.path!, toPath: dbPath)
            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
            }
            let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            if (error != nil) {
                alert.title = "Error Occured"
                alert.message = error?.localizedDescription
            } else {
                alert.title = "Successfully Copy"
                alert.message = "Your database copy successfully"
            }
            alert.delegate = nil
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()
        }
    }
```

where you can pass the file name(Database.sqlite3) in the function 

For complete demo of how use sqlite in swift you can refer to this site:[Sqlite demo swift](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-sqlite-database-swift)

In your code if you are trying to get the db file using your sample code it will give you the error as you are trying to retrieve the NSDictionary from the sqlite3 file which is not possible

plist file is stored in the NSDictionary structure so that code will execute properly

Comment: thanks, but when i use: let strDbPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Database", ofType:"sqlite3") - strDbPath is nil. Do you know why, please?

Comment: @ankmara Please try with this: let strDbPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Database", ofType:"sqlite") if that not work,  please clean and build the project again and chek if you have your 'Database.sqlite3'(check the spelling of the file) in the `Build Phases` of the `Copy Bundle Resources` of project